# access 2013 query replace null to 0 does not work?

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to create a query which I inserted some formulas but it has no result if there is any `NULL` in cells involved in a formula. I tried to replace `NULL` to `0` (not necessary to show the number `0`, just need a value so that the formula can work) with this `SELECT IIF(ISNULL([field]), 0, [field]) FROM [table]` but I don't know how to write it correctly in SQL view. Here is the entire SQL code:

```
SELECT [LISTING MASTER].Broker, [LISTING MASTER].Type,
[LISTING MASTER].[TransID], [LISTING MASTER].ACTIVE, 
[LISTING MASTER].[CANCELLED - CLIENT], [LISTING MASTER].[CANCELLED - TEAM], 
[LISTING MASTER].EXPIRED, [LISTING MASTER].[OFF MARKET], 
[LISTING MASTER].PENDING, [LISTING MASTER].[SOLD - EXTERNAL], 
[LISTING MASTER].[SOLD - INTERNAL], [LISTING MASTER].UNSIGNED, 
[ACTIVE]/[TransID] AS active1, [CANCELLED - CLIENT]/([TransID]-[ACTIVE]) AS CC2, 
[CANCELLED - TEAM]/([TransID]-[ACTIVE]) AS CT3, [EXPIRED]/([TransID]-[ACTIVE]) AS expired4
FROM [LISTING MASTER];
```

How can I change all the `NULL` to `0`? More particularly, I need `[ACTIVE]/[TransID] AS active1, [CANCELLED - CLIENT]/([TransID]-[ACTIVE]) AS CC2, [CANCELLED - TEAM]/([TransID]-[ACTIVE]) AS CT3, [EXPIRED]/([TransID]-[ACTIVE]) AS expired4` this part works.
If someone could fix it and paste the whole code so that I can just paste it in my SQL view, it would be great appreciated! I barely know coding... Thanks a lot.

[What the query looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jR8E.png)

[Design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2ouy.png)

Comment: If your barely know coding then either learn or employ someone. This is not a free code writing service. ***Or at least put some effort into your question so that it's easier for us to help you***: Format your query so it's readable, provide sample data and expected results. We can't guess what the requirements are.

Comment: `IIF(ISNULL([field]), 0, [field])` looks rights to me, what problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Sorry I'm too new to this.. Uploaded the query and design view, I can't link a third picture says need at least 10 reputation, working on that...

Comment: Sorry I'm too new to this.. Uploaded the query and design view, I can't link a third picture says need at least 10 reputation, working on that...It's just I  put "IFF(ISNULL([FIELD],0,[FIELD]))" in SQL view it says grammar error. It's my last week's homework but I still would like to learn, I would really appreciate it if you guys can help. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 2):

You may also be able to use the Nz() function as an alternative to the IIF:

```
Nz([field], 0)
```

See [this info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) about Nz().